# Displaying the node title in different region

Tags: theming

My designer just killed me, I realised he put node titles in a different region of the page layout, just beneath a menu and before left/right sidebars. No going back now.

How can I display titles of things (nodes, views etc) in a different region and hide it from the content region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to touch the template file and prefer to use the UI, you can also use the [Blockify](http://drupal.org/project/blockify) or [Omega Tools](http://drupal.org/project/omega_tools) module. Either one of these will put the page title into a block for you to place in any region of your choosing.

Comment: does your proposed solution work for rendering node and views titles?

Comment: yes it does. :)

Comment: - Step 1: enable blockify module.
- Step 2: update blockify settings to expose page title as block.
- Step 3: update omega tools settings to hide page title

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which version of Drupal you're using, but the method is basically the same. In D6 just place  where ever you need it in the page.tpl.php template and remove it from the node.tpl.php template (or use conditionals to output it there when needed).